# Special Price in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

When setting the Special Price in Magento back end a start date is required. This date is then populating the `news_from` field. The result is that if I give a product a special price it is also being identified as `New`
Magento 1.8.1.1

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I did have a look and a special end date isn't required. It also doesn't set the `news_from` field. You've got something wrong with your set up if it does.

Comment: special price is related to special_from_date and special_to_date. Though both are not required.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, although a lot of it is answering points never raised in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

A date isn't necessarily required for adding a special price. If you do want to put a date for the special price to begin and end then you should use the 'Special Price From Date' & 'Special Price to Date'. These can be found under the pricing section. This is separate from the news from and news to attributes. Hope this helps.